# How to pass a value from form(block) to the page and show this page?

Tags: 7, forms

I created a block with a form (elemnts: textfield and submit). Also have a page created by the hook_menu. I want that when you click on submit in block, the value from textfield transmitted to a page that is created using the hook_menu and show this page with data from textfield.
In the future I plan to transfer some text in the html markup or array.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [hook_menu and wildcards](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Here is an example:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Name',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Ok',
  );

  return $form;
}


function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/' . $form_state['values']['name'];
}

function MODULE_menu() {
  $items['path/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'TTITLE',
    'page callback' => 'my_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_page_callback($var) {
 return 'HELLO ' . $var;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A new page opens when you click on the submit. However, instead of the value of the textfield just says Arrey. If use return 'HELLO ' . $var['values']['name']; CMS shows an error that no value "values".

Comment: @user25795 This is just an example how to use hook_menu and pass values to that page.. And there can not be $var['values'] array in menu callback.. In your case it can be different..